How to copy the callstack with time costs from a Unity Profiler sample?
From the profiler window in Unity, I want to be able to copy as text: the call stack starting from a method up to the “root” method, including the duration of each method.
Is it possible to “hook” into this tooltip feature (shown below) so that I can add the timestamps to the call stack list?
Illustrating GIF: https://imgur.com/a/ifoJT36
i.e., currently it gives me:
AssetDatabase.V2.RefreshInternal
Application.Reload
MonoCompiler.Tick
Application.Tick
EditorLoop

But I want:
AssetDatabase.V2.RefreshInternal 2500ms
Application.Reload 1000ms
MonoCompiler.Tick 800ms
Application.Tick 400ms
EditorLoop 100ms

